c++ std::map::emplace() doesn't work but operator[] is ok
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

// 双向链表
struct ListNode {
    int times;
    unordered_set<string> bucket;
    ListNode *prev;
    ListNode *next;

    ListNode() {
        prev = nullptr;
        next = nullptr;
    }

    ListNode(int times, string key) : ListNode() {
        this->times = times;
        bucket.emplace(key);
    }
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, ListNode *> map;
    ListNode *node = new ListNode();
    map.emplace("haha", node);
//    map["haha"] = node;
    ListNode *node2 = new ListNode(1, "x");
    map.emplace("haha", node2);
//    map["haha"] = node2;
}


debug image:

debug screenshot

Why does the value corresponding to the keyword "haha" ​​not change?
It should be 0xec1e20 instead of 0xec1c90.
When I use operator[], I can successfully change the value corresponding to "haha".


std::map::emplace adds a new element with a given key - but only if this key does not already exists:

Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args, if there is no element with the key in the container.

(emphasis is mine)
In your case the first call to to emplace uses a new key, and therefore indeed adds an the entry to the map. But the second call to emplace uses a key which already exists, and therefore it does nothing.
On the other hand std::map::operator[] always returns a reference to an element in the map (either the existing one, or a newly added one if it doesn't).

Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key or x respectively, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

Via this reference you can always update the value under that key as you do in the second call.

thank you very much
